# Check if binding is soap protocol

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy, wsdl

I want to check, what protocol a binding of a webservice uses. 
For example:
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

Here we have 4 different bindings. I just want to get the soap binding on runtime.
My groovy code so far:

```
 Wsdl wsdl = Wsdl.parse(url)
 SoapBuilder builder = wsdl.binding().localPart(wsdl.getBindings().first().localPart).find()
```

How can I determine, which Protocol a binding uses?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
def getBuilderForSoap(Wsdl wsdl, String strOperation) {
    SoapBuilder buildertmp
    SoapBuilder builder

    wsdl.getBindings().each {

        buildertmp = wsdl.binding().localPart(it.localPart).find()
        if (buildertmp.binding.getExtensibilityElements().get(0).elementType.namespaceURI.contains("/soap/")) {
            builder = wsdl.binding().localPart(it.localPart).find()
        }

    }
    return builder

}
```

But I do not know if this is reliable for every webservice.
Any other suggestions?